What happens if an object hits stationary objects on a pulley?
What happens if an object with speed  $v_i$ and mass $m$ hits two bodies of equal mass (also $m$) on a frictionless pulley at rest, and the colliding body sticks to one of the bodies on the pulley?
I used conservation of mass and momentum to compute initial and final velocities, but the computation says that, in that case, the only possible initial and final velocities are $0m/s.$
Conservation of energy: $\frac{1}{2}mv_i^{2}=\frac{1}{2}(2m)v_{f}^{2}+\frac{1}{2}mv_{f}^{2}$
Conservation of momentum: $mv_i=2mv_{f}-mv_{f}$ thus $v_i=v_{f}$
I think something is wrong with the equation of conservation of energy, or the computation is actually correct.

In a collision, if two objects stick together kinetic energy cannot be the same before and after the collision. This is why it is called a perfectly inelastic collision. There is some force that does work to cause the relative velocity between the two objects to change magnitude, and hence kinetic energy must be lost.

Okay thanks. Is it enough to calculate $v _{f}$ from given conditions

@Johngreg yes that is usually fine
